# FFmpeg - Merge two images (.png) to video (.mp4) doesn't work

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I want to merge two images (names are not numbered in a sequence) to a video, but the result includes only a video of the first image.

I would appreciate any kind of help!

ffmpeg.exe -r 1/5 -i image_x.png -r 1/5 -i image_y.png -codec:v libx264 -vf fps=50 video.mp4

Output:

> Input #0, png_pipe, from
>   'C:\Users\khj\Desktop\SpeakerLayoutTool\Images_video\iamge_x.png':
>   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3840x2160, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc Input #1, png_pipe, from
>   'C:\Users\khj\Desktop\SpeakerLayoutTool\Images_video\image_y.png':
>   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 3840x2160, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc File 'C:\Users\khj\Desktop\SpeakerLayoutTool\video.mp4' already
>   exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png
>   (native) -> h264 (libx264)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [libx264 @
>   0000016c2a46e000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
>   AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 [libx264 @ 0000016c2a46e000] profile High 4:4:4
>   Predictive, level 5.2, 4:4:4, 8-bit [libx264 @ 0000016c2a46e000] 264 -
>   core 157 r2970 5493be8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 -
>   http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3
>   deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
>   mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
>   deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12
>   lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
>   bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
>   b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250
>   keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf
>   mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40
>   aq=1:1.00 Output #0, mp4, to
>   'C:\Users\khj\Desktop\SpeakerLayoutTool\video.mp4':   Metadata:
>       encoder         : Lavf58.27.103
>       Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 3840x2160, q=-1--1, 50 fps, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
>       Metadata:
>         encoder         : Lavc58.52.100 libx264
>       Side data:
>         cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1 frame=  250 fps= 22 q=-1.0 Lsize=     162kB time=00:00:04.94 bitrate=
>   268.1kbits/s speed=0.444x

Comment: How long do you want each image to be shown?

Comment: At the moment 5 sec

Comment: Sorry, you are right. My player plays the second frame for a very short time. I deleted my post.

Comment: I think my player doesn't like video with only two frames (I am using MPC-HC)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg.exe -loop 1 -t 5 -i image_x.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i image_y.png -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=0" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 video.mp4
```